# Differentiate style depends on select using SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have global css class with the name of `i-style`. I want to change its style depends on selector.  I know that it can be done by using class and `&.` selector. But I want to get it done by giving selector only.

for example

```
i-style{
 border:solid 1px black;
 &div{
  border-color:red;
} 
}

<span class="i-style"></span>
<div class="i-style"></div>
```

In that case `div` should have red color border.

Comment: If you just put the selector, it will assume you mean a `div` nested inside `i-style`. What you're asking for is syntax for something else.

Comment: What is your question? Are you looking for alternatives? Because `&div` is about as succinct as it gets.

Comment: The given code is not working. Is there any way to get it done in Sass style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question maybe this help you:

**SASS**

```
.i-style{
  border:solid 1px black;
  @at-root div#{&}{
    border-color:red;
 } 
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
.i-style {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
div.i-style {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: `at-root` was new to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Carlos, please try this. I hope this resolves your requirement

```
$selectorVar:'null' !default;
.i-style{
  border:solid 1px black;

  // build selector string
  $selectorVar: div+& !global;
  //$selectorVar: div+&, span+& !global; - for multiple selectors
}

#{$selectorVar} {
 border-color:red;
}
```

This generates output like

```
.i-style {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

div.i-style {
  border-color: red;
}
```

**Note:** Generally, I don't pollute global namespace!. Accept this answer if it helps